# "turn me into" idiom for hobbies

Tags: idioms, dictionaries

I have a vague memory of an idiom involving "turn me into" and hobbies, but I can't find it on dictionaries online. Maybe I'm using a wrong word?

"My friend turned me into DJing" would mean that my friend got me interested in DJing.

Does this idiom exist? Can you find it in Merriam Webster or any other online dictionary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're thinking of "turn him on to," as in "My friend turned me on to DJing."

*turn (someone) on to (something)* ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20%28someone%29%20on%20to%20%28something%29))

> to cause (someone) to use or become interested in (something) for the first time

Comment: Perhaps OP is mixing “turn on to something” with “to be into something”

Comment: @Stefan He could also be thinking of "He got me into something" which is a reasonable way of saying "He got me interested in something". You can use "He turned me into _an or a_  X" in this way but X has to be a noun for a _practitioner_ of the activity. That is you can say "He turned me into a cyclist" but not "He turned me into cycling"